# How to handling controller TextField on expandable Form

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm developing an app on flutter, I'm creating a view that contain form to input student data where is TextField can be expanded as much as needed. So when Icons.add button clicked, additional TextField show up.

And the problem is how to to set unique TextEditingController name for every TextField?

Here is my code:

```
class _StudentFormState extends State<_StudentForm> {
  final _addStudentForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();

  int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> children = List.generate(count, (int i) => _SingleStudent(i));

    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Form(
            key: _addStudentForm,
            child: Column(
              children: children
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                count += 1;
              });
            }
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SingleStudent extends StatelessWidget {
  final int index;

  _SingleStudent(this.index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          controller: _nameController[index], // problem here
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'NAME',
          ),
        ),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _emailController, // problem here
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'EMAIL',
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the ListView to a ListView.builder, and then, set a key to the TextField, and the key value will be the index parameter.

Comment: How would this fix the problem?

Comment: Because everytime when you add a new TextField, the index of the key will grow, like an array, will start at 0, 1, 2...

Comment: OK, that should be part of the answer!